# How can I append time to this command prompt date command

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to run a .bat file with command prompt to add time to the date.

Currently, I have this code

```
MOVE...\folder\^"Mytest %DATE:/=-%.csv^"
```

This produces

```
..\folder\Mytest Thu 12-06-2012.csv
```

I want to get

```
..\folder\Mytest Thu 12-06-2012 21:45.csv
```

Tried all kinds of things but failed miserably.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `move` requires a source and destination, so you haven't provided your actual effort (code). It's usually better if you do, because posting made-up code can often hide the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
 %date:/=-% %time:~0,5%.csv
```

The `%time%` uses the current time; the `:~` means "a substring of", and the `0,5` says "starting at the first character (index 0) and continuing for 5 characters", so the entire thing means "give me the first 5 characters of the output of `time`".

Using this at a command prompt:

```
C:\>echo %date:/=-% %time:~0,5%
```

outputs

```
Thu 12-06-2012 18:19
```

The format you're using is going to cause problems with sorting, though. My advice would be to drop the day of the week portion, and change the date output to `CCYY-MM-DD`, which will be much more useful when you're trying to find a specific date. You can use this:

```
echo %date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2% %time:~0,5%
```

which outputs

```
2012-12-06 18:33
```